# Nginx: auth_request doesn't pass user cookies to internal request

Tags: nginx

I am following the instructions at https://developers.shopware.com/blog/2015/03/02/sso-with-nginx-authrequest-module/ to protect some proxied web apps using Nginx's `auth_request` module.

I have the following lines in my `server` section. For every request that comes in, nginx will issue an authorization request to the auth server (auth.example.com).

```
auth_request /auth.php;

location = /auth.php {
    internal;
    proxy_pass https://auth.mydomain.com;
}
```

The authorization server is my own. I've written a PHP script that simply checks for the existence of the `PHPSESSID` cookie and checks for the `$_SESSION['username']` value that was set when the user originally authenticated.

However, because the reverse proxy is an internal one, the user's `PHPSESSID` cookie isn't being passed along to the authorization server.

How can I copy the `PHPSESSID` cookie from the original request to the internal authorization request?

### Troubleshooting attempts

This is my `auth.php` script. It uses two different 4xx status codes for debugging purposes.

```
<?php
if (! isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])) {
    http_response_code(403);    # No cookie
    exit;
}

session_start();

# Check to see if the session username is set
if (! isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    http_response_code(401);    # Unauthorized
    exit;
}
else {
    echo "OK " . $_SESSION['username'];
}
?>
```

I am pretty sure the cookie isn't being passed along because when I go to the authorization URL in my browser (https://auth.mydomain.com/auth.php), I get a 200 status code. My script returns 403 if the cookie isn't present. According to the Nginx logs, that's what it's getting back.

I have also tried the following `location` configuration, with no success. This one doesn't use an `internal` request, but is a regular `proxy_pass`.

```
location = /auth.php {
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
    proxy_pass https://auth.mydomain.com;
}
```